# Adding max method to return the largest element on list

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Our instructor told us to add a max method to return the largest element on the list and write the definition of the method max, The problem is since it already have a maxListSize which returns the maximum size of the list do I need to put a a max method again?

```
public abstract class ArrayListClass {
    protected int length;
    protected int maxSize;
    protected DataElement[] list;

    public ArrayListClass(){
        length = 0;
        maxSize = 100;
        list = new DataElement[maxSize];
    }

    public ArrayListClass(int size){
        if(size < 0){
            System.out.println("The array size must be positive. Creating an array of size 100...");
        }else{
            maxSize = size;
        }
        length = 0;
        list = new DataElement[maxSize];
    }
    //copy constructor
    public ArrayListClass(ArrayListClass otherList){
        maxSize = otherList.maxSize;
        length = otherList.length;
        list = new DataElement[maxSize];

        for(int j = 0; j < length; j++){
            list[j] = otherList.list[j].getCopy();
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return (length == 0);
    }

    public boolean isFull(){
        return (length == maxSize);
    }
    /*
     * method that returns the number of elements
     * in the list
     */
    public int listSize(){
        return length;
    }
    /*
     * method that returns the maximum size
     * of the list
     */
    public int maxListSize(){
        return maxSize;
    }

    /*
     * method that prints the elements of the list
     */
    public void print(){
        for(int index = 0; index < length; index++){
            System.out.print(list[index].getCopy() + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    /*
     * method that determines whether an item is the
     * same as the item in the list at the position
     * specified by location
     */
    public boolean isItemAtEqual(int location, DataElement item){
        return (list[location].equals(item));
    }
    /*
     * method that inserts insertItem in the list
     * at the position specified by location
     */
    public void insertAt(int location, DataElement insertItem){
        if(location < 0 || location >= maxSize){
            System.out.println("The position of the item to be inserted is out of range.");
        }else{
            if(length >= maxSize){
                System.out.println("Cannot insert in a full list");
            }else{
                for(int index = length; index > location; index--){
                    list[index] = list[index-1];
                }
                list[location] = insertItem.getCopy();

                length++;
            }
        }
    }

    public void insertEnd(DataElement insertItem){
        if(length >= maxSize){
            System.out.println("Cannot insert in a full list");
        }else{
            list[length] = insertItem.getCopy();
            length++;
        }
    }

    public void removeAt(int location){
        if(location < 0 || location >= length){
            System.out.println("The location of the item to be removed is out of range.");
        }else{
            for(int index = location; index < length; index++){
                list[index] = list[index + 1];
            }
            list[length-1] = null;
            length--;
        }
    }
    /*
     * method that retrieves the element from the list
     * at the position specified by location
     */
    public DataElement retrieveAt(int location){
        if(location < 0 || location >= length){
            System.out.println("The location of the item to be retrieved is out of range.");
            return null;
        }else{
            return list[location].getCopy();
        }
    }

    public void replaceAt(int location, DataElement repItem){
        if(location < 0 || location >= length){
            System.out.println("The location of the item to be replaced is out of range.");
        }else{
            list[location].makeCopy(repItem);
        }
    }

    public void clearList(){
        for(int index = 0; index < length; index++){
            list[index] = null;
        }
        length = 0;
    }

    public void copyList(ArrayListClass otherList){
        if(this != otherList){
            for(int index = 0; index < length; index++){
                list[index] = null;
            }

            maxSize = otherList.maxSize;
            length = otherList.length;
            list = new DataElement[maxSize];
            for(int index = 0; index < length; index++){
                list[index] = otherList.list[index].getCopy();
            }
        }
    }


    public abstract int seqSearch(DataElement searchItem);

    public abstract void insert(DataElement insertItem);

    public abstract void remove(DataElement removeItem);

    public abstract void removeAll (DataElement removeAllItem);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you elaborate?

Comment: SO is not for you to complete your homework. I can tell you that the method is easy to write. You just have to go through the elements, and keep another variable, which saves the maximum value. By the time you are done iterating through the list, you will have your max-size element. Also what does `The problem is since it already have a maxListSize to return the maximum size of the list.` means?

Comment: @nicomp Do I need to add another max method? Since there is already a method which return the maximum size

Comment: @Ralph.D I would assume your `max` method should return the maximum `DataElement` but you should ask the person who is setting the assignment.

Comment: @PeterLawrey That's what I know the method max returns it already.

Comment: @WeareBorg What do you mean by "You just have to go through the elements, and keep another variable, which saves the maximum value."

Comment: If you have such a method can you add it to the question, because I can't see it.

Comment: @Ralph.D No, the max method doesnt return this already. The ``maxListSize`` returns the maximum size of the list, not the ``biggest`` element. You should ask your instructor for clarification since you dont understand the assignment. You just dumped it here.

Comment: I just told you how to implement your assignment, no more help from my side. Over and out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you missunderstood the code you provide.

`maxListSize()` is actually the size of the **largest array** that can be built : the number of elements contained (it is simply a getter, giving the maxSize property).

Your instructor wants you to write a method giving the **largest element** contained in your array, regardless the size of your array. You have to define : "How can i say this element is larger than another element ?"
Then write your code and you are done.